# Looping a variable cyclically

Tags: python, loops

I have two integer values, one has significantly fewer digits than the other. For example:

```
x = 100
y = 1298411291836199301    (19 digits)
```

What would be the way to code it in Python so that x has the same number of digits by looping it, so I would want something like:

```
x =  1001001001001001001   (19 digits)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, is there anything you have tried to show.

Comment: Hi cobraclaire, can you please tell us what you've tried so far? This will make getting quality help much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the number of digits of an integer is merely a byproduct of how it is represented (base 10), you'll have to turn it into a string.

```py
x = 100
y = 1298411291836199301

x = str(x)
target_len = len(str(y))

while len(x) < target_len:
  x += x

# Cut off the last loop if it goes over the
# desired length, and turn it back into an int
x = int(x[:target_len])

# >>> x
# 1001001001001001001
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
x = 100
y = 1298411291836199301

n = len(str(y))
x = str(x)
m = len(x)
multiplier = n // m + 1

x = ''.join( # join an iterable of strings into a single string
    (x for _ in range(multiplier)) # generator expression that returns x multiple times
    )[:n] # truncate the final string to the exact desired length
x = int(x)

print(x)
print(y)
```

Output

```
1001001001001001001
1298411291836199301
```